# Highcharts Activity Gauge - how to get different behaviors while hover over

Tags: highcharts

I need help for 2 things please. My Activity gauge displays 2 series: Ring A and Ring B.

1) Instead of the default tooltip where the series name and % show in the middle while hover over, can I have it display the inner ring (B) name and % without hover over? And when user hovers over the outer ring (A), it would display the name and % for the outer ring and stays that way till user hovers over the inner ring again? This is more of a swapping kind of action.

2) I would also like to have a regular tooltip (round corner rectangle box like the tooltip for piechart) displaying strings of text that relates to each ring.

Expected behavior:
Activity gauge would show Ring B name and % in the middle of the gauge design when webpage is done loading. As user hovers over Ring A, tooltip box shows with a string of text describing Ring A. As user hovers over Ring B, Ring B name and % appears and stays in the middle of the gauge design with a tooltip box showing a string of text describing Ring B.

(I have tried many ways with my limited knowledge of js and highcharts, I cannot get this to work. Please help.)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing particulars of your exact chart code here are some ideas.

To get extra text in the tooltip you can create your data series like:

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 1,
    extraText: 'Some really neat long text containing some really important info'
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5,
    extraText: 'Some short text containing some really dull info'
}]
```

Then in the tooltip use the [`formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter):

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return 'The value for <b>' + this.key +
      '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>' +
                '<br >' +
                this.point.extraText;
  }
},
```

A live [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eansj2Lj/) of this extra text tooltip.

Now to get the first item in your conditions met I would use [`dataLabels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels) in conjunction with [`events`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.point.events) and handle mouse actions. Following the comment made by Paweł on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856708/show-datalabels-for-spiderweb-only-when-hovered-over-the-line-or-the-legend) answer you can get what you need.